# Return sub list from a list where the last element links back to the starting index into the list

Tags: python, list

How can you return a sub list from a list returning 3 consecutive elements where the last element links back to the first given any index into the list?

For example, given index `3` for `list = [1,2,3,4,5]`, would return `[4,5,1]`. Or given index `4` with list = `[1,2,3,4,5]`, would return `[5,1,2]`.

Options I have:

```
1. return list[index:] + list[:index+3]
2. return list[index:index+3] + list[:len(list)-index]
3. return list[index+3:] + list[:len(list)-index]
4. return list[index:index+3] + list[:max(0 , -1*(len(list)-index-3))]
```

Comment: If you already have the answers, then what is it that you want to know?

Comment: I don't have the answer. I have options out of these one is true.

Comment: @MayankPorwal It is totally reasonable to ask which way is best or is there a better way

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks. Can you plz help me on this that which one will be best suited option?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Agree. That is what I wanted to know from OP. Does he want a better solution, because, he didnt mention it anywhere in hi question that he wants to know the best solution out of the four options.

Comment: Please don't (even as an example) shadow built-ins, i.e. don't name your variable `list`.

Comment: @jpp ok sure...will take care

Comment: @jpp my friend told me to register for  udacity course to day [thisone](https://in.udacity.com/kpit-scholarship) and i found that this exact question is asked in the prerequisites.So my concern is that posting questions directly from a certain website wrong ? I mean people are screened on basis of certain questions and one them happened to be this.

Comment: @AlbinPaul, I don't work for udemy. If a question is poorly worded or written, this is independent of an external udemy course. They are not related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical use case for the [modulo operator `%`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]  # do not shadow built-in 'list'

i = 3
[lst[x % len(lst)] for x in range(i, i+3)]
# [4, 5, 1]

i = 4
[lst[x % len(lst)] for x in range(i, i+3)]
# [5, 1, 2]
```

From your given options, the last one (4.) is the one that yields the same results:

```
lst[i:i+3] + lst[:max(0 , -1*(len(lst)-i-3))]
```

This you can easily confirm by simply trying it out ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to know that out of given option which one is best suited one?

Comment: The last one is the correct one. Amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved using [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

def roll_n(x, index, length=3):
    return np.roll(x,-index)[:length].tolist()

roll_n(lst,3)
[4, 5, 1]

roll_n(lst,4)
[5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), from the documentation:

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   saved copy.

**Code:**

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def get(l, index, length=3):
    return list(islice(cycle(l), index, index + length))


print(get(lst, 3))
print(get(lst, 4))
```

**Output**

```
[4, 5, 1]
[5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
def return_consecutive(a, index, n=3):
    while index > len(a):
        index -= len(a)
    a.extend(a)
    return a [index:index + n]

return_consecutive(a, 3)
[4, 5, 1]
return_consecutive(a, 4)
[5, 1, 2]
return_consecutive(a, 6)
[2, 3, 4]
```

This also works for values greater than the length of the list

Answer (score 1):

Im suggesting one method but this involves generating a list twice the size of your current list

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> def roundlist(l,index,value):
...     return (l+l)[index:index+value]
... 
>>> roundlist(l,3,3)
[4, 5, 1]
>>> roundlist(l,4,3)
[5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways. For example, you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) via [`deque.rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) and then use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

L = [1,2,3,4,5]
k, n = -3, 3

dq = deque(L)
dq.rotate(k)
res = list(islice(dq, 0, n))

[4, 5, 1]
```